# Give the solution of twice outer join

Tags: sql

```
SELECT MaterialProcessSlip.*,
       Vendor.CompanyName   ,
       O.Name
FROM   MaterialProcessSlip ProcessSlip
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendors Vendor
       ON     (
                     ProcessSlip.SubContractorId=Vendor.Id
              )
              MaterialProcessSlip
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Operations O
       ON     (
                     ProcessSlip.Operationsid=O.id
              )
```

Comment: Explain. Also: edit your answer; select the SQL; use the "101010" button to mark the selected text as a code sample; resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking what's wrong with your code?

Given the complete lack of information I can only comment on syntactic issues there may be semantic ones too.

You have `MaterialProcessSlip.*` but you have aliased the table `MaterialProcessSlip` as  `ProcessSlip` so have no table with that exposed name.

so you would need to use `ProcessSlip.*` but you shouln't be using `*` anyway. You also have a table name added in apparently at random after your parentheses.

```
SELECT ProcessSlip.col1, ProcessSlip.col2,...
       Vendor.CompanyName   ,
       O.Name
FROM   MaterialProcessSlip ProcessSlip
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendors Vendor
       ON     (
                     ProcessSlip.SubContractorId=Vendor.Id
              )
             /* Removed -> MaterialProcessSlip*/
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Operations O
       ON     (
                     ProcessSlip.Operationsid=O.id
              )
```

Comment: +1 for effort, OP is obviously not trying to help us anyway.

Comment: @Hal - Thanks. I suspect this question is doomed to closure anyway!